# Clear Image on UIImageView subview of a MapView and draw new Image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

I draw a Gif image in a subview onto a Mapview. The Gif is not just rectangle. The new image will be rotated, so it's just not possible to draw the new image over the old. I need to clear the old image before draw the new. I can't find any solution to do this. This is my working code so far:

```
CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 260);
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(150, 300);
layer.position = center;
layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.gif"].CGImage;
layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleDegree * 3.14/180);
[[mapView layer] addSublayer:layer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the layer from mapView. Make sure you hold the reference to layer which loads the image.

```
[layer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

**EDIT:**

As you haven't provided me with much code I'll try my best provide solution as per my understanding of your situation buddy :)

```
- (IBAction)selectTime:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    NSString *eventHours = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
    currentHour = [eventHours floatValue];

    //some calculations

    if (self.imageLayer != nil) {
        //If image added earlier then this statement will remove it from superlayer which is your mapView
        [self.imageLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }

    self.imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    self.imageLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 260);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(150, 300);
    self.imageLayer.position = center;
    self.imageLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"angle.gif"].CGImage;
    self.imageLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(shadowDirection * 3.14/180);
    [[mapView layer] addSublayer:self.imageLayer];
}
```

As you can see I am accessing the same CALyer that I had used to add image to MapView. In order to be able to persist that I have created a property called `imageLayer` in my .m file.

You should ask the layer to remove itself from super layer to remove it.

Comment: For testing I've included the code with an if statement after my code. Was happened was, that the NEW image not showed up when the code was executed. Where do I have to put the code in?

Comment: @ggkey  Please add little more code with where did u try using this code, or where are u loading new Image and Ill let u know where n how to use the above code to achieve the required behavior

Comment: I use the code inside a picker function. With the picker I select the new angle, the image should rotate to it's new angle. The image with the old angle should be removed before the new image will be shown. Thx

Comment: Why does layer remove... not work? Any idea? I'm new on cocoa, so may be I did'nt understand the whole structure of the layers. Thx for some more proposals.

Comment: what do u mean by remove won't work ? What did u try ?

Comment: For testing I've added two layers with an image:                             [[mapView layer] addSublayer: layer];
[[mapView layer] addSublayer: layer2]; Then I've tried to remove one of them with: [layer removeFromSuperlayer]; -- no effect, image is still there.

Comment: When I use [[mapView layer] setSublayers:nil]; before, the map disappears, but the layer then will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different versions, insert at index, replace sublayer etc. The only version where the image works as it should was with: [[mapView layer] setSublayers:nil];  but the whole map disappeared.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
//etc.
}

- (IBAction)selectTime:(id)sender {

NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *eventHours = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
currentHour = [eventHours floatValue];

//some calculations

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 260);
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(150, 300);
layer.position = center;  
[[mapView layer] setSublayers:nil];  // map disappears, Image works :-)    
layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"angle.gif"].CGImage;
layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(shadowDirection * 3.14/180); 
[[mapView layer] addSublayer:layer];
}

- (IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender{

MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion region =
MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (userLocation.location.coordinate, 100, 100);
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

longLabel = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
latLabel = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fault in my case was, to use

```
CALayer *layer1 = [CALayer layer];
```

instead of

```
layer1 = [[CALayer alloc] init];
```

Now

```
[layer1 removeFromSuperlayer];
```

is working :-)